# why does function combine require parantesis in haskell?

Tags: haskell, haskell-prelude

```hs
Prelude> -- I have 2 functions: f and g
Prelude> f x y = x + y
Prelude> g x = 2*x
Prelude> f 2 3
5
```

To express `$ f(x, g(y))*` with x=2 and y=3 this work well:

```hs
Prelude> f 2 (g 3)
8
```

why does the following return error ?

```hs
Prelude>
Prelude> f 2 g 3

<interactive>:19:1: error:
    • Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num (a -> a)
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    • When checking the inferred type
        it :: forall a. (Num a, Num (a -> a)) => a
Prelude>
```

Comment: I believe you understand that `f a b c` calls `f` passing three arguments. `f 2 g 3` similarly passes three arguments.

Comment: For the same reason you would need `f(2, g(3))` instead of `f(2, g, 3)` using more traditional function call syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```hs
f 2 g 3
```

is (because function application **left-associative**):

```hs
f 2 g 3 = ((f 2) g) 3
```

that's why you get this error - it expects `g` there to be a `Num` (as it is the parameter `y` in `f x y = x+y` and `+ :: Num a -> a -> a -> a`)

`2` as a literal can be a value in every `Num a` but GHC does not know a instance for `Num` that is a function `a -> a`.

Now the error itself talks about the context - basic Haskell cannot have a constraints of the form `Num ((->) a a)` - but you could easily (and safely) circumvent this with the given extension ... then you should get the error with the type-class.

Comment: `Prelude> ((f 2) g)) 3`  and `Prelude> ((f 2) g) 3)` return both error: parse error on input ‘)’

Comment: is this a question? `(` and `)` need of course to be balanced

Comment: sorry I mean in your example they are balanced  `Prelude> ((f 2) g) 3` but  return `error:
    • Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num (a -> a) (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    • When checking the inferred type   it :: forall a. (Num a, Num (a -> a)) => a`

Comment: Yes, of course.  It's just that `((f 2) g) 3` more clearly demonstrates _why_ that error is happening.  (Or perhaps it'd be clearer with `(f 2 g) 3`.

Comment: @user3313834 I did not try to fix your issue (I think you have a working version right up in the question) - I hoped the problem might be more obvious with the parentheses in.

Comment: I got it now g is not int